# Eyelashes vertices

Tags: vertices, select

[image]I'm new at the blender and I'm trying get colour for eyelashes, I bought this body mesh and eyelashes is like a part of body it's not separated. Maybe there is an easier way to select all eyelashes vertices without clicking on them one by one or easier way how to get colour for them. I was trying select all them one by one and separate them but it's quite hard and takes a lot of time.

Comment: If this is a merged mesh then enter edit mode, hover over the eyelashes and hit L to select them then hit P > Separate by selection to separate them into a new mesh.

Comment: That's much better, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see, the lashes may not be attached to anything (independent mesh segments).  If that is the case I might do the following.  In my example,  a cylinder represents the mesh that is *not* the lashes, and several planes represent the lashes.  You see that the object "Mesh with lashes" contains all of these parts:

[image]

In Edit mode, I use the menu "Mesh::Separate::By Loose Parts".  The result is several separate objects.  I then then select *only* the lash object (not the mesh with *other*), and Join them into a single "Lash Object":

[image]

For the lash object in Edit Mode, I will "Menu::Select::All" and create a vertex group "lashes":

[image]

(I also create a vertex group call "other" in the "other" mesh).  I can now Join the Lash and Other objects into a single object, but the object continues to have the "lash" Vertex Group:

[image]

I can now select::None and then Select the "lash" Vertex Group, and

[image]

In Materials Properties, create a new Material slot (Lashes) that I can Assign only to the selected vertex in group "lashes":

[image]

[image] My example.

Comment: Thank you it helped get the colour for eyelashes and eyebrows